# How to handle URL with "/" in vue router and redirect to other component

Tags: vuejs2

I have got the url in this form `/#/isms/register/VYOYHDpg/oBkYmHlxtB8mQ==`

I have the `vue-router` configured as :

```
{
  path: "/isms/register",
  component: Layout,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":code",
      name: "WOTC URL page",
      component: ISMSHome,
      props: true
    }
  ]
}
```

In my `ISMSHome component`

```
created() {
    alert(this.$route.params.code)
  }
```

But, the route never reach the `ISMSHome component`, it couldn't redirect to anywhere in the app.

I couldn't now change the server code that generated that URL but i do have to make some work-round to redirect the browser from `register` pages to another page.

I had tried to pass the url parameter from the props to another component. But, that too didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
{
  path: "/isms/register/:code",
  component: Layout,
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      name: "WOTC URL page",
      component: ISMSHome,
      props: true
    }
}
```

**Note**: Remember that you need to add `<router-view />` inside your `Layout` component as well.

Comment: i used  `path: ":clientcode(.*)"` in the children..and seems it is solving the current solution. but i am not sure it is the elegant solution.